# Rich text format for response text in facebook chatbot

Tags: bots, chatbot, wit.ai, facebook-chatbot

I want to format(change font size/text color/apply text style - bold/underline/italic etc) the response text send to user in Facebook chatbot.

I do not see any such support in the messenger API. Just wanted to confirm if its supported or not? Is there any other way/approach to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,
picku

Comment: Hi Picku, You get success in changing the font/text size on facebook messenger chatbot?

Comment: Sorry Chetan, stopped work on chatbot year back. However i will try to go back and check last status of this work and will inform you for sure.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can accomplish something similar to what you want using the web view API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-extension

This allows you to display an HTML page without leaving the chat. If your responses are dynamic you could generate the pages at runtime and link to them using the API.

Comment: Perfect. I will try using the same. Thanks Bouke for the answer and the link.